# Expected Min/Max when picking numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose you pick two numbers between $0$ and $1$ with each number being picked at equal probability. What is the expected min/max of these two numbers? What if you picked ten numbers from $0$ to $1$?

I know you have to integrate something to compute this but I dont know how to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be $n$ samples from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$.  Let $M=\max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$.

For any particular $X_i$, $P(X_i<x)=x$ (for $x\in [0,1])$.  Thus $P(M\le x)=x^n$ for $x\in [0,1]$.  This gives the cumulative distribution function of $M$.  The probability density function of $M$ is obtained by differentiating the cdf.  Thus the pdf for $M$ is $nx^{n-1}$ for $x\in [0,1]$ (and $0$ elsewhere).

So $E[M]=\int_0^1 x\cdot(nx^{n-1})dx=\frac{n}{n+1}$.

For two selections, the expected maximum is $\frac23$.  For ten selections, the expected maximum is $\frac{10}{11}$.